# Enter key in C#

Tags: c#

I have a code like below

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)   
{
   if (e.KeyChar == 13)
   {
       if (!textBox1.AcceptsReturn)
       {
           button1.PerformClick();
       }           
    }
}
```

After I hit Enter, it'll send a message to another textbox and begin a new line. Can anyone help me to bring the cursor back to its first line?
I tried textBox1.SelectionStart, SelectionLength and Focus but it doesn't work, is there any another way?

Comment: Did you try to delete the last character of your textbox? It should be the new line.

Comment: @DanielShillcock I use winform

Comment: @ShikatsuKagaminara I'm making a chat app, it's very unconvienent to delete a line after press Enter, you know

Comment: When they press enter does the text from the textbox go into another component?

Comment: @aguertin it is solved, BTW, it just begin a new line when I hit Enter, just like hit Enter in MS Word, you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent that the keypress is passed on to the control by setting the `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` property to true:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        if (!textBox1.AcceptsReturn)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

As you mentioned in a comment that you are implementing a chat app, you also might want to implement the typical behavior of Shift+Return inserting a new line:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 13 && !e.Shift)
    {
        if (!textBox1.AcceptsReturn && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm waiting for 2 mins to accept your answer, it tells me to wait for 4 mins

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your helps, it'll try it

Answer (score 0):

To set cursor position to the beginning of a textbox, use the following...
I will hazard a guess that you didn't use these in combination with each other...

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Comment: Actually, I tried those and they were useless in my situation

Comment: Are you definitely selecting the correct textbox? :-)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that, but it was solved, thanks anyway